# opening a file based on user input c++

Tags: c++, file, io, user-input

I am trying to make a program that would open a file based on the users input.
Here`s my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string filename;
    ifstream fileC;

    cout<<"which file do you want to open?";
    cin>>filename;

    fileC.open(filename);
    fileC<<"lalala";
    fileC.close;

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it, it gives me this error:

```
[Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' and 'const char [7]')
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thank you...

Comment: Look at `std::ifstream`'s documentation.

Comment: ... and use `std::ofstream` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has several problems. First of all, if you want to write in a file, use `ofstream`. `ifstream` is only for reading files.

Second of all, the open method takes a `char[]`, not a `string`. The usual way to store strings in C++ is by using `string`, but they can also be stored in arrays of `char`s. To convert a `string` to a `char[]`, use the `c_str()` method:

```
fileC.open(filename.c_str());
```

The `close` method is a method, not an attribute, so you need parentheses: `fileC.close()`.

So the correct code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filename;
    ofstream fileC;

    cout << "which file do you want to open?";
    cin >> filename;

    fileC.open(filename.c_str());
    fileC << "lalala";
    fileC.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write to an `ifstream` because that is for *input*. You want to write to an `ofstream` which is an *output* file stream.

```
cout << "which file do you want to open?";
cin >> filename;

ofstream fileC(filename.c_str());
fileC << "lalala";
fileC.close();
```

Comment: it still gives me this error                                                                               [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(std::string&)'

Comment: @Hillman My mistake, the constructor for `std::ofstream` takes a `const char*` instead of a `std::string`, so call `.c_str()` off your file name.