# opening up more than one input file

Tags: c++, xcode

I am having trouble to create a menu where case 'I'- open both input files, case 'r' reads the files line by line into an array and finally  case 'cf' is to close the files. Right now it won't compile. For instance like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

std::ifstream inputFile1,inputFile2;

void openinputFiles();
void closeinputFiles();
void readFiles();

int main () 
{

     // menu

     case'i': // open files
     case 'I': openinputFiles();
     break;

     case 'cf': // close files
     case 'CF': closeinputfiles();
     break;

     case 'r': // read file line by line into array
     case 'R': readFiles();
     break;
}

void openinputFiles()
{
   std::cout << "Enter the input filename 1:";
   std::cin >> inputfileName;

   inputFile1.open(inputfileName);
   if(inputFile1.is_open())
      std::cout<<"File 1 Opened"<<std::endl;

   inputfileName.clear();

   std::cout << "Enter the input filename 2:";
   std::cin >> inputfileName;

   inputFile2.open(inputfileName);
       if(inputFile2.is_open())
          std::cout<<"File 2 Opened"<<std::endl;
}

void closeinputfiles() 
{
      inputFile.close();
}

void readFiles() 
{
     // Code
}
```

Comment: Please show how did you give the input and info about filename

Comment: what do you mean? @Sri lakshmi kanthan

Comment: show what is the input to your code and what is the filename ?

Comment: There are two input files and the names are: "test1.txt" and "test2.txt. Each file needs to be open one at a time when the user is asked for the filename and they enter one of them in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opening a file based on user input c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025936/opening-a-file-based-on-user-input-c)

Comment: When `won't compile` - can You give an error?

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile1,inputFile2;
    std::string   inputfileName;

    std::cout << "Enter the input filename 1:";
    std::cin >> inputfileName;

    inputFile1.open(inputfileName.c_str());
    if(inputFile1.is_open())
        std::cout<<"File 1 Opened"<<std::endl;

    inputfileName.clear();

    std::cout << "Enter the input filename 2:";
    std::cin >> inputfileName;

    inputFile2.open(inputfileName.c_str());
    if(inputFile2.is_open())
        std::cout<<"File 2 Opened"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Enter the input filename 1:text1.txt
File 1 Opened
Enter the input filename 2:text2.txt
File 2 Opened

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 11.545 s
Press any key to continue.
```

works fine for me.

EDIT:

you can not use string in case instead Try This,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    char str[3];

    std::cin>>str;

    if(toupper(str[0])=='C')
    {
        if(toupper(str[1])!='F')
             str[0]='\0';
    }

    switch(str[0])
    {
    case 'i': // open files
    case 'I': std::cout<<"Open";
    break;

    case 'c': // close files
    case 'C': std::cout<<"close";
    break;

    case 'r': // read file line by line into array
    case 'R': std::cout<<"Read";
    break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and you closeinputfiles() should be

```
void closeinputfiles() 
{
     inputFile1.close();
     inputFile2.close();
}
```

Comment: @randomp103  feel free to accept the answer, if you got it.

Comment: @randomp103   can you edit your post by adding above details ?, because it is easy to read.

Comment: I just did, Hope it is clearer to understand @Sri lakshmi kanthan

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Case statement without Switch statement! I don't know will it work with that, but try to add switch statement before jumping on Case.

And when you are closing file, you are using not defined object!!